# Error 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: javascript

Unable to convert base64 to blob. I have function defined like:

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;
    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

And I am calling the above function on `onchange()` of input element:

```
previewFile(e){

    var previewImage = self.root.querySelector("#previewImage");
    var file = self.root.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    if(file){
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        previewImage.src = "";
    }

    reader.onloadend = function(){
        var blob = self.b64toBlob(reader.result);
        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        previewImage.src = blobUrl;
    }
}
```

I get error like this: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

What string to be encoded in the case according to the error?

Comment: Why on earth do you create a blob out of a file? a file is a instance of a blob. get rid of the hole FileReader and b64toBlob thing and just call createObjectURL on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your base64 data because that could be one reason, try this.

```
   `let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
    this.base64Data = reader.result;
    console.log('before the change', this.base64Data);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);`
```

This will give you exact base64 value. Try this , this might solve your problem.